# How to send PDF attachment file in gmail using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, gmail, phpmailer, email-attachments

I want to send PDF attachment file in gmail account using php mailer (class.phpmailer.php) ?

```
<?php
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From      = '';
$mail->FromName  = '';
$mail->Subject   = '';
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$username." "."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Contact No.: ".$contact." "."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".$message." "."\r\n";
$mail->Body      = $MESSAGE_BODY;
$mail->AddAddress( '' );
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
$_FILES['file']['username']);
if ($mail->Send())
{   
  echo "Mail Sent";
}
else
{
echo "Could not send mail";
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer - send PHP generated PDF (mPDF) as attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407412/phpmailer-send-php-generated-pdf-mpdf-as-attachment)

Comment: Search before you post; this has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer class only lets you use Google's SMTP server.
You should send it the ordinary way. By using  $mail->AddAttachment($filePath);
If you have any specific problem please be more specific.

Comment: Still Not working :(

Please send my fill code of php

Answer (score 0):

Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting